# How to combine/join two results tables by the grouped by column?

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by

How can the two individual tables be combined into one results table?

The first query gives the results table
| company_id| Number products sold (2022) |
|-----------|-----------------------------|
| 1         | 151513                      |
| ...       | ...                         |
| 958       | 11156                       |

```
SELECT company_id, COUNT(product_id) AS 'Number products sold (2022)'
FROM Sales
WHERE sales_year = 2022
GROUP BY company_id;
```

And the second query gives the results table
| company_id| Number products sold (2021) |
|-----------|-----------------------------|
| 1         | 81513                       |
| ...       | ...                         |
| 958       | 10167                       |

```
SELECT company_id, COUNT(product_id) AS 'Number products sold (2021)'
FROM Sales
WHERE sales_year = 2021
GROUP BY company_id;
```

However, both tables should be combined to the following table
| company_id| Number products sold (2022) | Number products sold (2021) |
|-----------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
| 1         | 151513                      | 81513                       |
| ...       | ...                         | ...                         |
| 958       | 11156                       | 10167                       |

Answer (score 1):

use join in **subquery**  to put them in front of each other

| company_id | Number_products_sold_(2022) | Number_products_sold_(2021) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ids | Values(2022) | Values(2021) |

```
select a.company_id,'Number products sold (2022)','Number products sold (2021)' from 
(SELECT company_id, COUNT(product_id) AS 'Number products sold (2022)'
FROM Sales
WHERE sales_year = 2022
GROUP BY company_id) a
join 
(SELECT company_id, COUNT(product_id) AS 'Number products sold (2021)'
FROM Sales
WHERE sales_year = 2021
GROUP BY company_id) b
on a.company_id=b.company_id
```

if you want to put sales_year = 2022 followed by sales_year = 2021 use union

| company_id | Number_products_sold |
| --- | --- |
| Ids | Values(2022) |
| Ids | Values(2021) |

```
SELECT company_id, COUNT(product_id) AS 'Number products sold (2022)'
FROM Sales
WHERE sales_year = 2022
GROUP BY company_id;
union all 
SELECT company_id, COUNT(product_id) AS 'Number products sold (2021)'
FROM Sales
WHERE sales_year = 2021
GROUP BY company_id;
```